# SQL Server CE doesnt recognize DECLARE, BEGIN, COMMIT

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, sql-server-ce

I am trying to insert data in two tables in a single query. the second table requires the `scope_identity()` value from the first one.

My query is :

```
 String query = "DECLARE @questionID int;
            INSERT INTO question (questionText) VALUES(@question);SELECT @questionID = scope_identity();
            INSERT INTO topic_question(toppicID,questionID) VALUES(@topic,@questionID);";
```

Executing it as:

```
SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", question);
commandInsert.ExecuteScalar();
```

Got an error message:

> There was an error Parsing the query.Token Line number =1, Token line   offset =1, Token in error = DECLARE. ..........

I tried using `BEGIN TRANSACTION` in the beginning of the query and `COMMIT` at last of query. But still error remains. Can anybody please note, what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: SQL CE has a reduced instruction set; it wouldn't amaze me to hear that this isn't supported: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare variables in SQL Server CE and only one statement per command is allowed.

So you have to split your statement and execute it one-by-one like:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO question (questionText) VALUES(@question)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", question);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "select @@IDENTITY";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO topic_question(toppicID,questionID) VALUES(@topic,@questionID);"
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topic",.....);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionID", id);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note you have to keep your connection open (don't close it) after first call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in order for `select @@identity` to work.

Comment: Great answer Andy. Didn't know CE doesn't have this feature.